# Using Google Play Service in Cocos2d-JS

Tags: javascript, android, google-play-services, cocos2d-android, cocos2d-js

I am currently developing a game using Cocos2d-JS (http://cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Cocos2d-JS).
I want to integrate my game with google play service (https://developers.google.com/games/services/) for achievement and leaderboard.
I had done some research but i didn't find any tutorials. I had found some tutorials on Cocos2d C++.

Is there any way to integrate Cocos2d-JS with google play service ?
or can I export JS projects into Cocos2d C++ project or native android project ?

Many thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is similar to what you will do in cocos2dx. The second answer on [this thread](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/google-play-game-services/7190/3) (the one by explosis) answers it. Just a small change is needed. Insted of JNI calls to the methods updating leaderboard score from your scene code, you need to call java methods using java bridge as explained [here](http://cocos2d-x.org/docs/manual/framework/html5/v3/reflection/en).